# jsonpath: it possible to combine results into an object?

Tags: jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

With `jq` I can use `add` to combine results. I am looking for the `jsonpath` equivalent of this:

```
$ json="{\"nodes\": [{\"code\": \"DE\", \"label\": \"Germany\", \"ignore\": \"i1\"}, {\"code\": \"NL\", \"label\": \"Netherlands\", \"ignore\": \"i2\"}]}"
$ echo $json | jq '[.nodes[] | {(.code): (.label)}] | add'
{
  "DE": "Germany",
  "NL": "Netherlands"
}
```

Best I can up with is `$..nodes.[*].[code,label]`. However, this returns:

```
["DE",
 "Germany",
 "NL",
 "Netherlands"]
```

I am trying this website: https://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent JSONPath expression for the given jq query would be:

```
$.nodes[*]{"$[code]": "$[label]"}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
{
  "DE": "Germany",
  "NL": "Netherlands"
}
```